# Cloning git project with submodules using ansible

Tags: git, ansible

Although seemingly easy, my ansible set up hangs when trying to clone a git repo that has submodules. The 'parent' repo is cloned with no issue, but the ansible task is unable to clone the submodules and in fact hangs after this, almost as though there is some response it is expecting...

Here is my ansible task that clones the repo:

```
- name: Clone/Pull the {{ certificate_authority.repo.name }} repository
  become: yes
  git: repo="{{ ca.repo.url }}" force=yes accept_hostkey=yes clone=yes version="{{ git_branch | default(git_tag) }}"
       dest="{{ ca.repo.dest }}" key_file={{ ca.repo.key.location }}/{{ ca.repo.key.name }} recursive=yes track_submodules=yes
```

Any idea why ansible hangs cloning this repo?

Comment: Does running your playbook with `-vvv` yield any useful details? If you run `ps` when it's hanging, what is the `git` command line it's running? Are you able to clone it successfully from the command line on the same system?

Comment: Running with `-vvvv` includes the following interesting snippet `...Looking up /var/folders/z9/v1czs6dd7vb5jtq_0fr8f5y80000gp/T/tmp_lrYWR\r\ndebug3: Sent message fd 8 T:17 I:2\r\ndebug3: Received stat reply T:101 I:2\r\ndebug1: Couldn\'t stat remote file: No such file or directory\r\ndebug3: Sent message SSH2_FXP_OPEN I:3 ... SSH2_FXP_STATUS 0\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\n')`. Running `ps aux|grep git` shows the following are being run `

Comment: and running `ps aux | grep git` shows the commands running are `/usr/bin/python /tmp/ansible_6X_csE/ansible_module_git.py`, `/usr/bin/git submodule update --init --recursive --force`,`/bin/sh /usr/lib/git-core/git-submodule update --init --recursive --force` (for each of the 3 submodules),`git submodule--helper update-clone` and `/usr/lib/git-core/git submodule--helper clone --path lib/first-subproject --name lib/first-subproject --url https://reayn@bitbucket.org/reayn/first-subproject.git`. So it does seem that ansible is trying to clone the repos

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else getting this issue,  the resolution is to ensure that your submodules in the `.gitmodules` file use the `git` protocol i.e. `ssh://git@....`

Comment: +100 I couldn't understand why ansible git module was prompting me for a password when doing a git pull manually worked fine. Obviously it turned out that I wasn't pulling the sub-modules when doing the pull manually so it was a false positive when it worked manually.